# Не работает фильтр

Tags: веб-программирование, servlet, http, jsp, java

Поставил фильтр на jsp страницы и на сервлет.

```
public class PageFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse responce,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, responce);
    // ((HttpServletResponse) responce)
    // .sendRedirect((((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath()));
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

В web.xml все прописал.
По идее должен пропускать. Но отображается 404. Без фильтра все хорошо.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А сюда что приходит: `FilterChain chain`?

Comment: FilterChain -- interface.
представляет собой следующее звено в цепочке фильтров.
вызов дуФильтр() должен вызывать запрашеваемый ресурс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вызываете редирект, то `chain.doFilter(request, responce);` не нужен. 
Только вот если фильтр стоит на все страницы и на все сервлеты без всяких условных ограничений, то можете впасть в рекурсию. Т.е. изначально вы делаете редирект и на следующей странице (на которую вы вызвали редирект) все фильтры идут по новой.
Хотя если честно, то и я могу ошибаться, но для собственного Security фильтра, если пользователь пытается зайти на страницы, на которые у него нет прав доступа, я делал именно так.

Comment: Не, редирект там закоменчен.

Comment: @Jan Bronnikau, т.е. это просто фильтр без ничего? проверьте еще раз web.xml, и посмотрите в дебаге, заходит ли вообще в фильтр

Comment: так.. щас у меня вообще томкат не запускается. Может дело не в фильтрах...

Comment: @Jan Bronnikau, кстати да, если используете какой IDE - пересоберите проект

Comment: Все в порядке. Вопрос исчерпан.